# Converting Java class initiation to Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring

I hope to find some help in converting Java class initiation to spring beans. I have not worked much with spring beans and getting a variety of errors. Java version works no problem.

Java version:

```
SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());
```

Spring bean:

```
   <spring:bean id="ssl_strategy" class="org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy" init-method="init"/>       
   <spring:bean id="ssl_builder" class="org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder" init-method="loadTrustMaterial(null, ssl_strategy)">
```

I'm getting an error that TrustSelfSignedStrategy  has no method "init". The error :

```
 Couldn't find an init method named 'init' on bean with name 'ssl_strategy'
```

But once I remove init-method="init" from the first bean, then I get an error for .loadTrustMaterial method:

```
Couldn't find an init method named 'loadTrustMaterial(null, ssl_strategy)' on bean with name 'ssl_builder'
```

EDIT #1: I also have tried using org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean as follows and this is so far the closest I think:

```
<spring:bean id="ssl_strategy" class="org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy" /> 
<spring:bean id="ssl_builder" class="org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder" />

<spring:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="ssl_builder"/>
   <spring:property name="targetMethod" value="loadTrustMaterial"/>
   <spring:property name="arguments">
    <spring:list>
        <spring:value>null</spring:value>
        <spring:value>ssl_strategy</spring:value>
    </spring:list>
    </spring:property>
</spring:bean>
```

But the above results in the  following error:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

Could someone please post here what would be the right way to have the above Java as Spring beans?

... much appreciate your time.

Comment: Dude, nobody uses Spring XML anymore. Use Java `@Configuration`classes and let the IDE and compiler help you.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments you are passing are strings. IE the string "null" and the string "ssl_strategy".
Try the following which should pass an actual `null` and the reference to the `ssl_strategy` bean:

```
<spring:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <spring:property name="targetObject" ref="ssl_builder"/>
   <spring:property name="targetMethod" value="loadTrustMaterial"/>
   <spring:property name="arguments">
    <spring:list>
        <spring:null />
        <spring:ref bean="ssl_strategy"/>
    </spring:list>
    </spring:property>
</spring:bean>
```

Comment: Just the reason not to use XML. OP couldn't have made this mistake using JavaConfig.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no one uses Spring XML anymore, mostly because it's 2017, and somewhat because XML is not type-safe, and the IDE can't help you (to some extent IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate can, but you have to pay for it).

Second of all, I don't think a global SSL connection factory is a very good idea; with SSL, you want to keep it localized as much as possible and not have a singleton bean hang out for everyone to muck with.

That said, your Java code can simply be made into as bean, like this:

```
@Bean
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory() {
    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());

    return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());
}
```

Put the above in a `@Configuration` class and that's it!

Comment: I was thinking because I'm in apache Camel context, the SSL objects wont be accessible anywhere else.  Or would it still be an issue? If that's the case, then yes, I'd keep it locally to one of camel routes.

Comment: My Camel script is called multiple times a second, so I'd rather keep it slim. Also the env it runs in is behind a firewall on a secure, closed system.

Comment: @user2917629 I'm not saying it's accessible outside the JVM. I'm saying any class in the application can get hold of it.